# Asynchronous insert into Elasticsearch

Tags: python, asynchronous, elasticsearch

In the middle of a webapp request/response cycle, I want to insert into elasticsearch something which might take a few milliseconds or a few seconds. Naturally I don't want to block the cycle. Does elasticsearch support an asynchronous insert (with its own message queue)? If so, how is this done? If not, how would you go about implementing this (for example, sending to a message queue, then having a worker that does nothing but check the queue and insert stuff from the queue into elasticsearch)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch's [bulk inserts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) are asynchronous. You can use the [Elasticsearch.bulk](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.bulk) python API or the slightly more convenient [elasticsearch.helpers.bulk](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.bulk) API for this.

Comment: Just to be clear. "bulk inserts are asynchronous" means that as soon as the request is received, elasticsearch returns OK before doing the inserts, the webapp cycle continues, and in parallel elasticsearch does the inserts?

Comment: It is possible to configure how soon the call returns using the Write Consistency parameter [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-consistency]. By default it is set to "quorum", which means that as soon as some set number of nodes have received the write requests it will return. BTW - this is the behavior for single inserts as well, it is just faster from the network i/o point of view to send all the objects in bulk.

Comment: Alright, so I guess that's the right answer then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is a redis server for  queue management . And push all insert/jobs to redis.

sudo apt-get install redis-server

and then this http://python-rq.org/docs/

Comment: I don't get it. My problem isn't that I don't know how to use a queue, but instead that I'm not sure what the correct way is to pull from the queue into elasticsearch. Is there a canonical way to do it, or do I have to code a cron job that checks the queue once in a while and pushes to elasticsearch? Is there to tell elasticsearch where to look for queues? etc.

Answer (score -1):

The native java client support this by default see .. [Java client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-api.html)

i was using the PHP client , but was very slow in terms of big operations.

we started to polyglot(PHP-Java)

The PHP application Generate the json => send it to a java application on a different port   and  the java ES client forward our Json in Async and exit.

We got a better performance , we just had some time/issues to set up the java client using the maven repository , but once it's  done , you will feel the difference in the application speed .